SearchBar doesnt show search results from axios api immediately, only after reopening component
I have an issue with search results not being displayed immediately under search input in command component. I see results in console and for example for replay it is not empty, but on UI I see Loading... for split second and then nothing is shown under the input. But when I close and open search command again - results are populated correctly. Can someone suggest the solution here? Maybe I am doing data fetching in a wrong way or not rerendering command component? I am pretty new to NextJs and learning as I develop something. Appreciate any help.
I am using Next.js 14.2.3
Here is the code for command:
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { search } from "@/services/apiClient";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  CommandDialog,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
  CommandList,
  CommandSeparator,
  CommandShortcut,
} from "@/components/ui/command";
import { Calendar, Smile, Calculator, User, CreditCard, Settings } from "lucide-react";
import { logger } from "@/lib/pinoLogger";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function CommandDialogLayout() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState({ live_tvs: [], matches: [], replays: [] });
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const [forceRender, setForceRender] = useState(0); // Added for forced re-render

  useEffect(() => {
    const down = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (e.key === "k" && e.metaKey) {
        setOpen((open) => !open);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", down);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", down);
  }, [results, query, open]);

  // Assuming you've defined `setIsLoading`, `setResults`, and `setForceRender` correctly.
  useEffect(() => {
    // Clear previous results when the query is empty or changes.
    if (!query) {
      setResults({ live_tvs: [], matches: [], replays: [] });
      console.log("No query");
      return; // Early return to skip unnecessary processing.
    }

    // Debouncing mechanism
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true); // Indicate loading state
        try {
          const data = await search(query); // Assuming `search` is a function that fetches data based on `query`
          //console.log("Search results:", data); // Log the fetched data
          //logger.info("Search results", data); // Also log using a more formal logger if available

          setResults(data); // Update state with the fetched results
          setForceRender(prev => prev + 1); // Trigger a re-render explicitly if necessary
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Search failed", error); // Log errors if the fetch fails
          logger.error("Search failed", error);
        } finally {
          setIsLoading(false); // Reset loading state
        }
      };

      fetchData(); // Execute the fetch operation
    }, 500); // Set a delay of 500 ms

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId); // Cleanup function to clear the timeout if the component unmounts or the query changes
  }, [query]); // Dependency array containing `query` to re-run the effect when it changes

  const handleQueryChange = (value: string) => {
    setQuery(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        size="sm"
        variant="outline"
        className="relative h-8 w-full justify-start rounded-[0.5rem] px-3 text-sm text-muted-foreground sm:pr-12 md:w-40 lg:w-64"
        onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
      >
        <span className="hidden lg:inline-flex">Search...</span>
        <span className="inline-flex lg:hidden">Search...</span>
        <kbd className="top-1.3 pointer-events-none absolute right-1.5 hidden h-5 select-none items-center gap-1 rounded border bg-muted px-1.5 font-mono text-[10px] font-medium opacity-100 sm:flex">
          <span className="text-xs">⌘</span>K
        </kbd>
      </Button>
      <CommandDialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <CommandInput placeholder="Type a command or search..." value={query} onValueChange={handleQueryChange} />
        <CommandList>
          {isLoading ? (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          ) : (results.live_tvs.length === 0 && results.matches.length === 0 && results.replays.length === 0 ? (
            <CommandEmpty>No results found.</CommandEmpty>
          ) : (
            <>
              {results.live_tvs.length > 0 && (
                <CommandGroup heading="Live TV">
                  {results.live_tvs.map((item: any) => (
                    <CommandItem key={item.id} onSelect={() => router.push(`/live-tv/${item.id}`)}>
                      {item.name} - {item.country}
                    </CommandItem>
                  ))}
                </CommandGroup>
              )}

              {results.matches.length > 0 && (
                <CommandGroup heading="Matches">
                  {results.matches.map((item: any) => (
                    <CommandItem key={item.id} onSelect={() => router.push(`/matches/${item.id}`)}>
                      {item.name} - {item.team1} vs. {item.team2}
                    </CommandItem>
                  ))}
                </CommandGroup>
              )}

              {results.replays.length > 0 && (
                <CommandGroup heading="Replays">
                  {results.replays.map((item: any) => (
                    <CommandItem key={item.id} onSelect={() => router.push(`/replays/${item.id}`)}>
                      {item.name} - {item.team1} vs. {item.team2}
                    </CommandItem>
                  ))}
                </CommandGroup>
              )}
            </>
          ))}

          {/* <CommandSeparator />
          <CommandGroup heading="Suggestions">
            <CommandItem>
              <Calendar className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              <span>Calendar</span>
            </CommandItem>
            <CommandItem>
              <Smile className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              <span>Search Emoji</span>
            </CommandItem>
            <CommandItem>
              <Calculator className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              <span>Calculator</span>
            </CommandItem>
          </CommandGroup>
          <CommandSeparator />
          <CommandGroup heading="Settings">
            <CommandItem>
              <User className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              <span>Profile</span>
              <CommandShortcut>⌘P</CommandShortcut>
            </CommandItem>
            <CommandItem>
              <CreditCard className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              <span>Billing</span>
              <CommandShortcut>⌘B</CommandShortcut>
            </CommandItem>
            <CommandItem>
              <Settings className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              <span>Settings</span>
              <CommandShortcut>⌘S</CommandShortcut>
            </CommandItem>
          </CommandGroup> */}
        </CommandList>
      </CommandDialog>
    </div>
  );
}

I am using this axios method:
export const search = async (query: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await apiClient.get(`/search?q=${query}`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

and I am using CommandDialogLayout inside of main-nav.tsx:

export function MainNav() {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [showAccountToggle, setShowAccountToggle] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowAccountToggle(true);
  }, []);

  const handleLinkClick = (e: React.MouseEvent, href: string) => {
    if (!user && !Object.values(PUBLIC_ROUTES).includes(href)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      router.push(PUBLIC_ROUTES.LOGIN);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex h-16 items-center space-x-2 bg-background-bgSubtle sm:justify-between sm:space-x-0">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-start">
        <Logo />
        <Separator
          orientation="vertical"
          className="ml-6 mr-5 hidden h-6 rotate-[30deg] gap-0 text-background-textContrast md:inline-block"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-end space-x-4">
        <nav className="flex items-center space-x-1">
          <div className="mr-3">
            {layoutConfig.mainNav?.length ? (
              <nav className="hidden gap-3 md:flex">
                {layoutConfig.mainNav.map((item) => (
                  <Link
                    key={item.href}
                    href={item.href}
                    onClick={(e) => handleLinkClick(e, item.href)}
                  >
                    {item.title}
                  </Link>
                ))}
              </nav>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <CommandDialogLayout />

          {/* Conditionally render AccountToggle after hydration */}
          {showAccountToggle && (user ? <AccountToggle /> : (
            <Link
              href={PUBLIC_ROUTES.LOGIN}
              className="button-ghost rounded-md border px-2 py-1 text-xs font-normal"
            >
              Login
            </Link>
          ))}
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

I tried to change data fetching approach to use api/search/route.ts and useSWR but both produce the same result

Might be a race condition issue? u have a timeout mechanism at useEffect but i think its not deboucing correctly due to it has just a timeout delay and its being trigger on every query change
